# Select element when clicked on it jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

How can I get attribute 'id' of an element when clicked on it using jquery or simple javascript. I tried:

```
$(document).one("click",function(){
console.log(this);
}
```

It logs the complete document object which makes sense as I am using  document with selector, But how do I get the id of the element when I click on it. The element can be SVG or PATH or a DIV.

**Sample HTML**

```
<div id="main">
<div id="middle">
<svg id="main_svg">
  <path>// code for path</path>
  <svg><rect>//code for rect</rect></svg>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

I want id of the element which is inside the "main_svg" SVG tag when I click on it.

Comment: Please look up how DOM events work. there are many things you can access in the event hash of the callback.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "getting the element" when you click on it? are you talking about an attribute of the element or its inner html?

Comment: @Ted I mean getting an attribute

Comment: @Arihant what attribute? ID? Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get both the element tag and its id:

```js
$("#mySvg").click(function(event) {
    var elemTag = $(event.target).prop("tagName");
    var elemId = $(event.target).attr("id")
    alert("this is a <" + elemTag + ">. Its id is: " + elemId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySvg" width="400" height="400">
<rect id="myRectangle" width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)"></rect>
<path id="myPath" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: This also returns a document element

Comment: The returns the `document` element when you use `event.target`. I am not sure why this was marked as accepted. But to each their own...

Comment: This for me returns the proper element id and tag. I am using contextmenu() with this.

Comment: Well, I can't see in the question that the OP doesn't want return the document element. Anyway, if the OP kindly unaccept this answer I can delete it.

Comment: So in my context, Everything is drawn dynamically inside the main_svg so I just changed the selector from document to #main_svg. So this is still the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [all selector](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) to bind the event for all elements inside the `SVG`.

For all elements inside :

```
$('#main').on('click', '*', function(){
    console.log(this);
})
```

But I guess you can and want to avoid all the elements and just target the direct childrens:

```
$('#main').on('click', '> *', function(){
    console.log(this);
})
```

---

**Notes**

1. In your code you have the id `main` twice on the div and on the SVG, `ID` must be unique so you can't have the same for both elements.
2. Note the use of the all selector can slow down the performance of your page, so maybe there is another way to get your goal.

Comment: @DaniP thanks for the live example. I whipped up a similar solution but since you've answered already, kudos to you!

Answer (score -3):

Use the `originalEvent` property to get the target:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#main').on("click",function(e){
        // Returns the element clicked on
        console.log(e.originalEvent.target); 
        // Returns the id of the element
        var clickedElemId = e.originalEvent.target.id;
        if (clickedElemId) console.log(e.originalEvent.target.id)
    });
});
```

Provided you change your markup to have one element with the id 'main'.

Comment: That will return document element

Comment: @PrakharSingh Shhh! I did not want to be so direct ;-)

Comment: If the OP doesn't click on an element then yes it will. That makes sense?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Surely using this method will negate any negative performance as a result of using the jQuery all selector.